# why .take() didn't take the specific number of items with flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, split, sublist

I have a list that I extract it into sublists and then I splitted it into sublists of 20 items.
Now I want to take juste 200 items of this list and then split it But .take didn't work for me.

```
 static Future<List> localPath() async {
    File textAsset = File('/storage/emulated/0/RPSApp/assets/bluetooth.txt');
    final text = await textAsset.readAsString();
    final bytes = text
        .split(',')
        .map((s) => s.trim())
     
        .map((s) => int.parse(s))
        .toList();

    int chunkSize = 20;
    final dd = bytes.take(200);
    print("BYTES : $dd");
    List<int> padTo(List<int> input, int count) {
      return [...input, ...List.filled(count - input.length, 255)];
    }

    List<int> padToChunksize(List<int> input) =>
        padTo(input.toList(), chunkSize);
    final items =
        bytes.slices(chunkSize).map(padToChunksize).take(200).toList();

    return items;
    //return items;
  }
```

even when I tried the code below I didn't get the expected output

```
return items.take(200).toList();
```

this is how I use the function:

```
    final chunks = await Utils.localPath();

 await Future.forEach(chunks, (chunk) async {
      final d = chunk as List<int>;
      await c.write(d, withoutResponse: true);
      await c.read();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
    });
```

Comment: take works just fine: `final i = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; print(i); print(i.take(3));`

Comment: @pskink for my case items are sublists not list maybe this cause the problem. I also updated my question check it please

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>.take()` return `Iterable<T>`

so if you want to return it as List call `toList()`

```
return items.take(200).toList();
```

Comment: Actually I tried this but always I got more than 10 sublists

Comment: it's resolved by updating the code inside foreach loop : `await Future.forEach(chunks.take(10), (chunk)`  Actually because chunks is a list of sublists so I have to take from it directly 10 items

Answer (score 0):

```
items.expand((e) => e).take(200).toList();
```

Comment: this disn't resolve the problem also